# CakePHP 3 Auth Logout-Error: Authentication adapter "loginAction" was not found

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

For some reason the CakePHP Auth Component won't let me log out.

Strangely this error occurred only recently and I can't remember changing anything at the Auth Component at my CakePHP 3 app.

Im setting up the Auth component the following way:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'User',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'Form' => [
            'finder' => 'auth',
            'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session'
    ]
]);
$this->Auth->allow();
```

Login works as expected, but when I logout with `$this->Auth->logout()` I get the following error:

**An Internal Error Has Occurred**
**Error: Authentication adapter "loginAction" was not found.**

Then, when I remove the array `'loginAction'` from the Auth Component completely the error changes to **Error: Authentication adapter "storage" was not found.**

It seems to work though, when I load the component without any params:
`$this->loadComponent('Auth')`

For the login I need my Auth component set up like described above. Its similar like CakePHP does it in its docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Any Ideas why CakePHP wont let me logout anymore all of a sudden?

Answer (score 2):

Oh my! I cant beleave I wasted all those hours...

The Auth params are messed up, thats how they should look like:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
     'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'User',
        'action' => 'login'
     ],
     'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'finder' => 'auth',
            'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
        ],
     ],
    'storage' => 'Session'
]);
```